# pass php json_encode to jQuery function

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to pass a php array to a jQuery function but I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')'. Expected either a closing ']' or a ',' following an array element.

my code:

```js
function showDetails(data) {
  alert(data); 
}
```

```html
<a onclick="showDetails(<? echo json_encode($arr['data']['items']); ?>)">
Click here
</a>
```

Comment: What else have you tried.. update that into your answer. Q moved to editing.

Comment: Without seeing the rendered html it's difficult to say exactly what's wrong, but something in the output is breaking that link.  Run the page and do a `view source` - post the actual link, not PHP.  Also, I removed the jQuery tag as there's nothing relevant to jQuery in the question.

Comment: Use single quotes for the onclick attribute due to json double quotes

Comment: @charlietfl > this was the solution which I found a few seconds before :D. Thanks :)

Comment: You should post the html endresult

Answer (score 3):

Use single quotes for the onclick attribute due to json double quotes which will cause html to break

```
<a onclick='showDetails(<? echo json_encode($arr['data']['items']); ?>)'>
```